# Programming Fully Implicit Heat Conduction in a Solid Plate

Tags: numerical-methods, linear-programming

I need to solve the equation:[image]

With
[image]

and[image]

I Would like to have dirichlet boundary conditions and I need to solve the problem fully implicitly. Here is my code, can anyone help? I am having problems with the boundary conditions (I want the edges to be 573K). I am solving in the form Ax=b. If anyone has an example of this or can help me with mine that would be great. (I am programming in MATLAB).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Physicist137 I am asking how to properly impliment the dirichlet boundary conditions in this fully implicit solution. And if I am anywhere close.

Comment: Most likely people on MSE are not going to read your code in detail. You should at least fully characterize the problem (except for exact values of parameters) in words in your question itself. In particular, you have not made it clear (except perhaps in your code, which I didn't read) what the geometry is. If the geometry is just a rectangle, then the finite difference solution to your problem solves for the temperature in the interior of the domain and the boundary values are simply forced to be equal to their Dirichlet values (for purposes of computing Laplacians and possibly for plotting).

Comment: One other thing I will warn you about: assuming that $1/d$ is an integer in floating point (simply because it is an integer in reality) is a very bad idea. It may work for certain particular values of $d$ but for others it will be off-by-one after floating point rounding, which will be a very insidious bug that you will struggle to find. Instead, you should set $N$, which would be equal to $1/d$, as an *exact* integer, and make $d=1/N$. In your case this amounts to $N=40;d=1/N$. (Same thing for dt, you should hardcode the number of steps, not the value of dt.)